normal probability density function
I want the function visualization as the picture but my code have issue that I dont know how to fix:
\begin{align*}
    f(x) &= \frac{1} {sigma}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi } \e ^ -\frac{ 1/2}\biggl(\frac{ x - \mu}{ \sigma})^2
\end{align*}



In the future please provide a MWE (e.g. a complete, compilable example of what you have tried so far)

The issue is with missing closing brackets. It's a good idea to start over, building a formula piece by piece, compile as often as you doubt to find out the problem easily.
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\bigr)^2}
\end{align*}

If it's a standalone formula, there is no need for align here, you could simply use display math
\[
  f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\bigr)^2}
\]



Using a complete code with your original fonts (Cambria Math) I suggest to use the \exp notation:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}

\[
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)
\]

\end{document}


